# No wp_query when $_POST isset with array of authors in Wordpress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, post

My form is posting the content from checkboxes to an ajax based Wordpress wp_query. The checkboxes are used as a filter for displaying posts. One of the checkboxes sets the author-id like this:

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check_author[]" id="<?php echo $author['name']; ?>" value="<?php echo $author['id']; ?>" checked>
    <span class="checkName"><?php echo $author['name']; ?></span>
</label>
```

The `$_POST['check_author']` outputs the following (depending on checkboxes checked):

```
Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 1 )
```

These id's are indeed correct and corresponding with the authors.

Next, I insert the array in my query.

```
$filters = $_POST['check_location'] || $_POST['check_themes'] || $_POST['check_author'] ;

    if( isset( $filters ) )

        //print_r($_POST['check_author']);

        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'tax_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'location',
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => $_POST['check_location'],
                ),
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'category',
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => $_POST['check_themes'],
                )
            ),
            'author'=> $_POST['check_author'],

        );

    //print_r($args);

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

But `$_POST['check_location']` and  `$_POST['check_themes']` are working like a charm and are correctly filtering my query.

I cant seem to get the author part working. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `author` as key, use `author__in`

Comment: Thank you! This indeed creates a successful filter within the query. Regrettably this creates a sort of 'relation' => 'AND' situation. Is there a way to query with this without excluding the different queries?

Comment: That answer is a no....because it is neither inside relation not inside any meta query, it is an argument like post type. If that solution worked for you , you can accept it ;)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try without the `'relation' => 'OR'...` ? Cause, I am not sure about the `'operator' => 'IN'`.

Comment: 'Operator' is indeed not needed in the query, i removed it but the author is still not properly filtered.

Answer (score 0):

The value you have for `$_POST['check_author']` is an array but you're using it with the `author` argument which expects an integer.

`author` is for a single author ID whereas `author__in` accepts an array of author IDs. Update your argument name to resolve the issue.

Documentation: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Author_Parameters